# Close and recreate controller when navigate through pages using bottom navigation bar on GetX Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have created bottom navigation bar for 4 pages. Is it possible to make it create the controller only when I tap and close when I navigate to another page?

In my case, I want it to create A's controller only when I tap A page and then when I go to B page, close A page's controller and create the B another page's controller. If I go back to A page, then recreate the A page's controller again.

Just like using `Get.offAllNamed()`. The reason I want to do this is to reload the page if the stream data inside the page changes especially to `Obx()` method used in every page.

Also reset any form inside a page if some of its field selected, for example like selecting a value from a dropdown menu and navigate to other page. When navigate back, reset the dropdown back to default.

I put my appbar and bottom nav in separate files and link both files to a pagewrapper.

All 4 pages controller were set on pagewrapper bindings like this:

```
class PagewrapperBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<PagewrapperController>(
      () => PagewrapperController(),
    );
    Get.lazyPut<AppbarController>(
      () => AppbarController(),
    );
    Get.lazyPut<SidenavbarController>(
      () => SidenavbarController(),
    );
    Get.lazyPut<HomeController>(
      () => HomeController(),
    );    
    Get.lazyPut<ApplyiptController>(
      () => ApplyiptController(),
    );
    Get.lazyPut<ResultiptController>(
      () => ResultiptController(),
    );
    Get.lazyPut<ProfileController>(
      () => ProfileController(),
    );
  }
}
```

PageWrapper controller and view:

```
class PagewrapperController extends GetxController {  
   BottomnavbarController bottomnavbarController =
      Get.put(BottomnavbarController());
      
  final bodyRoutes = [
    const HomeView(),
    const ApplyiptView(),
    const ResultiptView(),
    const ProfileView(),
  ];
}

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: const PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
    child: AppbarView(),
  ),
  endDrawer: const SidenavbarView(),
  body: Obx(
    () => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 10,
        right: 10,
      ),          
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: controller
                .bodyRoutes[controller.bottomnavbarController.bottomNavIndex.value],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: const BottomnavbarView(),
);
```

my bottom nav controller and view:

```
class BottomnavbarController extends GetxController {
  var bottomNavIndex = 0.obs;  
}

return Obx(
  () => BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: controller.bottomNavIndex.value,
    onTap: (index) {
      controller.bottomNavIndex.value = index;
    },
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    showSelectedLabels: false,
    showUnselectedLabels: false,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.black87,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.black38,
    items: const [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: "Apply IPT"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_sharp), label: "Result IPT"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: "Profile"),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hi @Richmond, did you get a chance to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion to get expected results.

1. Use [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html) to save the state of your screen
2. Create one common controller on main screen and access the controller on child screen. Use constructor to access that controller.

---

```
class ExampleController extends GetxController{
//your code
List<StatelessWidget> screens(ExampleController controller){
    return [AScreen(
    controller: controller,
  ),
  BScreen(
    controller: controller,
  ),
  CScreen(
    controller: controller,
  ),
  DScreen(
    controller: controller,
  ),];
}}
```

Please check this link. I have written a demo for you. https://pastebin.com/ZassgnJQ

Comment: this is literally the same as GetX state. The controller were not deleted from memory after navigating to another page. My question is not related to this. All I need is to delete the controller when navigating to another page. When I go back to the previous page, recreate and initialize the controller again.

Comment: Get.delete<YourController>(); Try this one. This will delete your controller.